# How to use scrollVerticallyBy() with Android RecyclerView and LayoutManager?

Tags: android, scroll, layout-manager, android-recyclerview

I would like to scroll by a certain amount of pixels in y direction in my recyclerview. I know that there are methods like `scrollToPosition()` or `scrollToPositionWithOffset()`. However, those don't really fit my needs.

I saw that `LayoutManager` provides a method `scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state)`. That sounds like what I want.

How do I use it? What are `recycler` and `state`? I didn't find any examples online, so some code would be useful.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 16):

I don't know about `scrollVerticallyBy`, that looks more like a internal method for the `RecyclerView`.
Aren't you just looking for the methods `scrollBy(int x, int y)` and `smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy)`?

From the documentation:

> public void scrollBy (int x, int y)
>
> Move the scrolled position of your view. This will cause a call to onScrollChanged(int, int, int, int) and the view will be invalidated.
>
> Parameters
> x   int: the amount of pixels to scroll by horizontally
> y   int: the amount of pixels to scroll by vertically

You can use the methods like so:

```
recyclerView.scrollBy(0, 50); //Scroll 50 pixels down
recyclerView.scrollBy(0, -50); //Scroll 50 pixels up
```

The same goes for `smoothScrollBy`.

Comment: Ruben is totally right, `scrollVerticallyBy` is a internal method that you override when you're building a custom LayoutManager. For more info about its use take a look [here](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/)

Comment: scrollBy(int x, int y) and smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy) is not supported in RecyclerView so your suggestion will not work

Comment: What do you mean by "is not supported"? I used those methods in a project and they worked fine.

Comment: recyclerView.scrollBy() is not optimum metod when large set on items and have to set initial scroll. recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollVerticalBy() is way faster

Comment: tested and doesn't work. the reason might be that is a method related to the view, not to the LayoutManager which should be the one in charge of that.